# How can I get regex to recognize "//" and anything that's not a slash appended to ".com" is invalid?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex that should test whether a url is valid.
Although it works for some URLs, it recognizes "www.google.comkjjkljkl" as valid, although it is not. Only [www.google.com/jkgjklkl](http://www.google.com/jkgjklkl), would be valid.
Similarly, a url such as "www.google.com/jkljkl//jkjkljk" is seen as valid, however, double "//" should not be allowed. Anyone know what is missing in the regex below? Thanks.

```js
const validateUrl = (value: string | null): string => {
        const regex = /^(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,})+$/gm

    if (value === null || value === '') {
      return ''
    }
    if (!regex.test(value)) {
      return ''
    }
    return 'Invalid'
  }
```

Comment: You should probably use an existing parser like the built-in [URL interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) instead of trying to invent your own regex. [URLs are complicated](https://www.netmeister.org/blog/urls.html), and if you try to write your own parser, you will probably get it wrong. (In fact, most of the existing parsers out there have slight inconsistencies with each other and with the specifications.)

Comment: `www.google.comkjjkljkl` is syntactically valid. There doesn't happen to be a `.comkjjkljkl` top-level domain, but there's nothing preventing it from being created.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Regex

```js
/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:(?:\w+\.){1,2}\w{2,3})(?::\d+)?(?:\/\w+)*(?:\/|\/\w+\.\w{3,4}|(?:\?(?:\w+=\w+&)*\w+=\w+)?)$/gm
```

It matches `http://www.google.com/jkgjklkl` but not `http://www.google.comjkgjklkl`

It also avoids double forward-slash URLs `//`

```js
const validateUrl = (value) => {
    const regex = /^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:(?:\w+\.){1,2}\w{2,3})(?::\d+)?(?:\/\w+)*(?:\/|\/\w+\.\w{3,4}|(?:\?(?:\w+=\w+&)*\w+=\w+)?)$/gm
    return (value === null || value === '' || !regex.test(value)) ? 'Invalid' : 'Valid'
}

console.log(validateUrl('http://www.google.com/jkgjklkl'))
console.log(validateUrl('http://www.google.com//jkgjklkl'))
console.log(validateUrl('http://www.google.comjkgjklkl'))
```

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9yp1oI/4)**

Tell me if it's not working...